# how can i get the right style props for the react-native styles?

Tags: typescript, react-native

When trying to get the appropriate styles for my react native app, it says that it does not work for the button styles.

How can I make the type error disappear?

```
interface TextButtonProps {
  buttonStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  labelStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  click: () => void;
  text: string;
}

interface Styles {
  button: ViewStyle;
  icon: ImageStyle;
  label: TextStyle;
}

const TextButton: React.SFC<TextButtonProps> = ({ buttonStyle, text, click }): JSX.Element => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({
    button: buttonStyle,
  });
```

error:

```
Type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle'.ts(2322)
TextButton.tsx(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'button' which is declared here on type 'Styles | NamedStyles<Styles>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `buttonStyle` might be `undefined` and the method `create` doesn't support the value `undefined`

```
buttonStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>; // ? means it can be undefined (a.k.a optional)
```

You have to check that `buttonStyle` is not `undefined`, you can do so by:

```
const TextButton: React.SFC<TextButtonProps> = ({ buttonStyle, text, click }): JSX.Element => {
  if (!buttonStyle) return; // Or a proper alternative return value

  const styles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({
    button: buttonStyle,
  });
}
```

Or if you're 100% sure that at the time of passing the `buttonStyle` argument it won't be `null` or `undefined`, you can use the non null assertion operator `!`

```
const TextButton: React.SFC<TextButtonProps> = ({ buttonStyle, text, click }): JSX.Element => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({
    button: buttonStyle!, // <--- Here
  });
}
```

Comment: can you give a more specific working example? using an if statement doesn't seem to solve the problem of it being undefined.

using a ternary also comes up with other problems

Comment: The `if` statement tells typescript that you are somehow handling the possibility of the variable being `undefined` or `null`, the following code will narrow the possible types that the variable now carries. In your case `buttonStyle` starts by having possible types of: `ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle | undefined`, right after the `if` check it will narrow to only `ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle`. It is up to you to handle the case where `buttonStyle` is `undefined,` you can throw an error or just return something else.

Comment: the null assertion operator worked :) thankyou